# Borel measurable function and sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R}^{n}\to [0,+ \infty] $ 2 Borel measurable functions. Show that {${x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}| f(x)<g(x) } $} is a Borel set.
I don't know how to start with the problem. At the beginning I thought I maybe could divide it into small intervals, but the function must not be continuous, so I don't know...
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For $r\in \mathbb{Q}$, put $A_r=\{x; f(x)<r\}$ and $B_r\{ x; r<g(x)\}$. (These sets can be empty; $A_r$ is certainly empty if $r<0$, but this is not a problem). Show that if $A$ is your set, then
$$A=\cup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}} (A_r\cap B_r)$$

Comment: How do you show that these sets are borelian? ( I mean A and B)

Comment: @jens Well, $A_r=f^{-1}(-\infty,r)$

Comment: Oh Yes of course!! I'm sorry. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

f-g is measurable thus $(f-g)^{-1}((\infty,0[)$ is Borelian

Comment: As $f$ and $g$ can take the value $+\infty$, how you define $f-g$ ?